# Возвращение значимых типов в .NET

Tags: .net

Рихтер в своей книге описывает условиях при которых лучше использовать значемый тип, вместо ссылочного и есть такой пункт:

> Размер экземпляров типа велик (более 16 байт), но экземпляры не
>   передаются в качестве параметров метода или не являются возвращаемыми
>   из метода значениями.

С передачей в методы- это понятно, так как будут издержки на передачу переменных в метод

Однако, я не понимаю, что плохого в том, что бы их возвращать из метода? Или получается, что будут такого же рода издержки, как при передачи переменных в метод?